# How to add mutli module structure at android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, module

I'm trying to learn Multi-module Architecture. I imported an app from GitHub to have a look at the architecture hoping it will help me.

I encountered a problem when creating the structure of the module as shown on the image below

[image: Here is an image of structure]

I am looking for help on how to set-up the structure.

Comment: Did you not find: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html

Comment: Of course I did find it, but it has a old layout

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1)

[image]

2)
[image]

This would create the blue squared module.

Comment: Thanks. Could I also put some android librarys in the kotlin libraray? (That I would have such a structure: edit_feature -> edit_data ,edit_domain, edit_ presentation)

Comment: If you would like to add an android library to kotlin/java library, you can do so, by right click on the recent created module
New>Module>Android Library> Finish

Comment: Thanks, thats working, but then I always have to delete the kotlin class and java folder. Is there maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

File > New > New Module.

[You can find more in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects)

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but what module should I pick? (I'm new to this topic)